# How to run cURL commands in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram-api

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 and I need to execute the following command in my application:

```
curl -F 'client_id=126581840734567' -F 'client_secret=678ebe1b3b8081231aab27dff738313' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=https://uri.com/' -F 'code=AQBi4L2Ohy3Q_N3V48OygFm0zb3gEsL985x5TIyDTNDJaLs93BwXiT1tyGYWoCg1HlBDU7ZRjUfLL5HVlzw4G-7YkVEjp6Id2WuqOz0Ylt-k2ADwDC5upH3CGVtHgf2udQhLlfDnQz5NPsnmxjg4bW3PJpW5FaQs8fn1ztgYp-ssfAf6IRt2-sI45ZC8cqqr5K_12y0Nq_Joh0H-tTfVyNLKatIxHPCqRDb3tfqgmxim1Q' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

so that it returns something like:

```
{"access_token": "IGQVJYS0k8V6ZACRC10WjYxQWtyMVRZAN8VXamh0RVBZAYi34RkFlOUxXZnTJsbjlEfnFJNmprQThmQ4hTckpFUmJEaXZAnQlNYa25aWURnX3hpO12NV1VMWDNMWmdIT3FicnJfZAVowM3VldlVWZAEViN1ZAidHlyU2VDMUNuMm2V", "user_id": 17231445640157812}
```

Is there a way to make Rails execute those types of commands? I was trying the following:

```
uri = URI.parse('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({
  "client_id" => "126581840734567",
  "client_secret" => "678ebe1b3b8081231aab27dff738313",
  "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
  "redirect_uri" => "http://nace.network/",
  "code" => params[:code]
  })    


res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

but I get the following error:

```
end of file reached
```

in this line:

```
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

Comment: Ruby has a number of [HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) that are better choices than reverting to Net::HTTP. Net::HTTP is good for writing your own app from scratch when nothing else exists, but you're reinventing a wheel that's been created many times well. If you want to use cURL, look at https://rubygems.org/gems/curb/versions/0.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using HTTPS, so you need to add this to your code:

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  res = http.request(request)
end
```

But if you don't need persistent connections, you could also use this:

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 
  "client_id" => "126581840734567",
  "client_secret" => "678ebe1b3b8081231aab27dff738313",
  "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
  "redirect_uri" => "http://nace.network/",
  "code" => params[:code]
)
```

Also, you could consider using a library like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday), which is a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: thanks. ok, it no longer shows me the error but how can I get the response values?

Comment: @jeff which of the two did you try?

Comment: @jeff I've made a change to the first example; the `res` comes from `http.request()`

Comment: the first example, the variable "res" is the one that should show me the response data?

Comment: yeah, that would be the one

Comment: I try to show the value of the res variable in the view but it shows me the following: valor: #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x00007febefbac150>

Comment: it should have a `res.body` to tell you why the request failed, but that would be another question

Comment: @jeff if this has answered your question, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*

This is from TinMan's comment below, sound points.

*Using cURL from inside Ruby or Rails is extremely valuable. There is an incredible amount of functionality inside cURL that isn't implemented in Rails or Ruby; Even Ruby's HTTP clients have a hard time replicating it, so cURL is very acceptable depending on the needs of the application. And, depending on the application, because cURL is in compiled C, it could easily outrun pure Ruby clients.*

Curl is a means of issuing HTTP (or HTTPs) requests from the command line.

You don't want to use CURL in Rails. You want to issue HTTP requests from within Rails. Using curl is okay, it's one way to issue HTTP requests from with Rails.

We can refine that down further to, you want to issue HTTP requests from Ruby. Narrowing/distilling down to the most basic version of the problem is always good to do.

We knew all this already probably - still worth writing down for us all to benefit from!

## Use HTTP in Ruby

We want to use a HTTP Client. There are many but, for this I'm going to use [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) (a gem) 'cause I like it.

You've made a good start with Ruby's built in `NET:HTTP` but I prefer Faraday's DSL. It results in more readable and extendable code.

So, here is a class! I barely tested this so, use as a starting point. Make sure you write some unit tests for it.

```
    # This is a Plain Old Ruby Object (PORO)
# It will work in Rails but, isn't Rails specific.
require 'faraday' # This require is needed as it's a PORO.

class InstagramOAuth
  attr_reader :code

  # The code parameter will likely change frequently, so we provide it
  # at run time.
  def initialize(code)
    @code = code
  end

  def get_token
    connection.get('/oauth/access_token') do |request|
      request.params[:code] = code
    end
  end

  private

  def connection
    @connection ||= Faraday.new(
      url: instagram_api_url,
      params: params,
      ssl: { :ca_path => https_certificate_location }
    )
  end

  def instagram_api_url
    @url ||= 'https://api.instagram.com'
  end

  # You need to find out where these are for your self.
  def https_certificate_location
    '/usr/lib/ssl/certs'
  end

  def params
    # These params likely won't change to often so we set a write time
    # in the class like this.
    {
      client_id: '126581840734567',
      client_secret: '678ebe1b3b8081231aab27dff738313',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: 'https://uri.com/'
    }
  end
end

# How do we use it? Like so

# Your big old authorisation code from your question
code = 'AQBi4L2Ohy3Q_N3V48OygFm0zb3gEsL985x5TIyDTNDJaLs93BwXiT1tyGYWoCg1HlBDU'\
       '7ZRjUfLL5HVlzw4G-7YkVEjp6Id2WuqOz0Ylt-k2ADwDC5upH3CGVtHgf2udQhLlfDnQz'\
       '5NPsnmxjg4bW3PJpW5FaQs8fn1ztgYp-ssfAf6IRt2-sI45ZC8cqqr5K_12y0Nq_Joh0H'\
       '-tTfVyNLKatIxHPCqRDb3tfqgmxim1Q'

# This will return a Faraday::Response object but, what is in it?
response = InstagramOAuth.new(code).get_token

# Now we've got a Hash
response_hash = response.to_hash

puts 'Request made'
puts "Request full URL: #{response_hash[:url]}"
puts "HTTP status code: #{response_hash[:status]}"
puts "HTTP response body: #{response_hash[:body]}"
```

When I ran the snippet above I got the following. The class works, you just need to tweak the request params until you get what you want. Hopefully the class demonstrates how to send HTTP requests in Ruby/Rails.

```
Request made
Request full URL: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=126581840734567&client_secret=678ebe1b3b8081231aab27dff738313&code=AQBi4L2Ohy3Q_N3V48OygFm0zb3gEsL985x5TIyDTNDJaLs93BwXiT1tyGYWoCg1HlBDU7ZRjUfLL5HVlzw4G-7YkVEjp6Id2WuqOz0Ylt-k2ADwDC5upH3CGVtHgf2udQhLlfDnQz5NPsnmxjg4bW3PJpW5FaQs8fn1ztgYp-ssfAf6IRt2-sI45ZC8cqqr5K_12y0Nq_Joh0H-tTfVyNLKatIxHPCqRDb3tfqgmxim1Q&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Furi.com%2F
HTTP status code: 405
HTTP response body:
```

## Additional Reading

. https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/

. https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates

Comment: Using cURL from inside Ruby or Rails is extremely valuable. There is an incredible amount of functionality inside cURL that isn't implemented in Rails or Ruby; Even Ruby's HTTP clients have a hard time replicating it, so cURL is very acceptable depending on the needs of the application. And, depending on the application, because cURL is in compiled C, it could easily outrun pure Ruby clients.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks @theTinMan. I accept your points, I'll read up on it. Should I update the answer?

Comment: I think it'd be worth acknowledging that cURL can be accessed via Curb, and there are many ways to get to where the OP wants to go. libcurl is an extremely powerful tool in the *nix world.