# How to Parse Json with Bearer Token in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, bearer-token

I have recently graduated a Bootcamp and trying my luck in some projects and applying for jobs.
Got a test, for this potential job, that I don't know how to tackle exactly. At this stage, kind of just wondering how to solve the test.

I need to create a website and display a list of all of the buildings, from this real estate company via their API. They have provided me with the token for the access already.

However, I'm not entirely sure how to connect with their API via Ruby. They gave me an example of how to connect but I haven't seen this before.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer token_they_provided" https://theirsite/api/buildings.`

Any assistance to point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thank you all!

Comment: Curl is a simple terminal tool that allows to ping an address across the web. Just typing the string they provided (with your own token) in your terminal will return the buildings. Once this works just use it in your app. Probably you will get a json as result and will need to parse it. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679761/how-to-run-curl-commands-in-rails )

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help. I will give it a try! Appreciate the support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is pretty much simple. You can just add [HTTP gem](https://github.com/httprb/http) (there are other options, like [Faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)) to your project, which turns everything even simpler.

**Using HTTP Gem**

1. Add it to your Gemfile
2. Install using bundle
3. Fetches API as below:

```
response = HTTP[Authorization: "Bearer #{token_they_provided}"].get("https://theirsite/api/buildings")
```

4. Parse JSON body:

```
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

You can read the gem docs for more information. Also, feel free to connect me via LinkedIn